# Gmail Emails Script

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail-api, google-authenticator

New to Google APIs so please bear with me.

**What I want to do?**
I need to write a script that will catch each email sent to a gmail account and perform some operations on the text and the email address it came from.

**How to do it?**
Well, this is my question. I was looking at GMAIL API and it looks exactly the thing I want. BUT the problem is my script will run in "forever" mode and Gmail requires OAuth 2, so is there anyway I can hard code the auth tokens and make the script run forever without it asking me for the Auth.

**OR**

Is there any webhook type thing for google that will send events to my WebServer first?

Comment: Yes, look for examples that use a .p12 file.

Comment: Could this tutorial help you https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/appengine ? It's a tutorial named "Leveraging Google App Engine services from scripts" for https://scripts.google.com service.